French passport has my maiden name
My French passport shows my first name followed  by my maiden name followed by the word "spouse" followed by my married name.
My Australian passport shows my first name followed by my married name only.
Can I enter Vietnam on my EU passport coming from Australia please, concidering the difference in names on my passports. Or, must I go on my Australian passport, ask for an online visa and have a shorter travel? As the rules are different for each country. Thank you

Normally you can choose whichever passport you like to enter a country as a foreigner (and normally you should use the same passport to leave it), but I'm not posting an answer because I don't know whether there is an exception that would apply in this case.

Thank you I appreciate

Problem may arise if there is some API (advanced passenger information) which need to be sent to the destination country before or during your flight. In such case, use same name for ticket and entry, and show the other passport at exit (you may get extra questions about name, so you may need to show the other passport). Things are more complex if one of the country (or both) "doesn't like" double passports.

Please do not post the same question again. If you think the close reason of the earlier question is not right edit that question with the information missing. Stack Exchange sites try not to get many almost identical questions.
